# MVC Filename property mapped to <input> tag so Filename property = selected filename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MVC5 EF6 C#

I have a Create view for an Image class. The Image class contains the string Property "ImagePathLocal".

I have the following on the view, to let the user select a file to upload:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Select Image", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">                
            <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="btn btn-default" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePathLocal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have to use

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="btn btn-default" />
```

as there isn't an equivalent @Html.InputFor(model => model.ImagePathLocal... etc. to use - My Googling has lead me to believe I have to do it this way (Correct me if I'm wrong)

When I click submit, the ModelState isn't valid, as the ImagePathLocal isn't populated. The file is successfully sent and I can save to the server (if I step over the validation).

So the question is, how can I allow the user to select a file and then populate the ImagePathLocal Property with the name of the file they've selected so that when the form is submitted, the Model.ImagePathLocal is populated and therefore the ModelState will be valid?

Edit:
Thanks to @Ehsan, the main answer was that I needed to use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImagePathLocal, new { type="file", @class="btn btn-default"})
```

However, I was wanted to populate 2 Properties once a user selected a file. My string property, which was the filename, and my HttpPostedFileBase property, which was the file the user selected. I changed the form so that the user was selecting the HttpPostedFileBase property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { type="file", @class="btn btn-default"})
```

and I hanged that property so that whenever it gets set, it automatically sets the string property:

```
private HttpPostedFileBase _image;
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _image;
        }
        set 
        {
            _image = value;
            ImagePathLocal = _image.FileName;
        }
    }
```

This achieves exactly what I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use overload of [`TextBoxFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which takes `htmlAttributes` as parameter   :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImagePathLocal, new { type="file", @class="btn btn-default"})
```

you can also use `input` but then  it's name should be your Model property name which is `ImageLocalPath` like this:

```
<input type="file" name="ImageLocalPath" id="ImageLocalPath" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Comment: Thanks - getting me closer, I'd like to use the first option, but when I do I get the string "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper" as the Property value, rather than the filename. Any Idea why? edit - also does the same with the 2nd option

Comment: File is posted in it, Wrapper will have property to get file name

Comment: My ImagePathLocal property is a string though - not an HttpPostedFileBase so I can't unwrap it...?

Comment: Why it is not HttpPostedFileBase?

Comment: All I need to save in the database is the filename, not the actual image. What I'm trying to do is let the user select a file. This goes to the server where the file upload is handled and then the filename is saved to the database.

Comment: so when file is uploaded you can'T get its name ?? its not clear what you trying to achieve, From posted file you can get name, if you don't want to save file don't save

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75012/discussion-between-rick-and-ehsan-sajjad).

Comment: Managed it - thanks for your help. Added the details to the question. The bigeest help was your @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImagePathLocal, new { type="file", @class="btn btn-default"}) - I didn't know you could do that - still learning.

Comment: @Rick you can always refer to  MSDN docs for help, here is list of TextBoxFor overloads available:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx